# The graphics filter was unable to convert this file while adding image in InlineShapes

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am developing an module, which will open existing word document and replace images in it with their new version on server.

images i get from the link https:///widgetFiles/10659.png

I am using following code to add image:

```
 var imagePath = @"https://<domain>/widgetFiles/40659.png";

 cell.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imagePath, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

But i am getting following error :

```
The graphics filter was unable to convert this file.

   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShapes.AddPicture(String FileName, Object LinkToFile, Object SaveWithDocument, Object Range)
   at icrm.console.process.WidgetReportProcess.WidgetReport.ProcessEventChart()
```

I am not able to identify the the issue, as this is working fine on developement and staging server but not working on production server with the same office configuration.

I tried to run application as administrator, giving write access to folder where word file is being created, but nothing worked

Please guide, how i could get rid of the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [InlineShapes.AddPicture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/inlineshapes-addpicture-method-word) method accepts a local path and file name of the picture. So, you need to download the picture on a local machine and add a picture from a hard drive, not a web server.

Comment: This worked for me,  but confused bcoz it was working on local and staging environment and not on production :(

Comment: @VikasNale You shouldn't be using the Interop server-side - it's not supported. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office